# CSS how do you fix something vertically for scrolling while not horizontally overlapping when zooming in?

Tags: css, positioning, fixed

So I have a div element in the center that has the main content of the page and then another div on the right for navigation. The div on the right has position:fixed; so that while you scroll down the center content it remains on the right side. When I zoom in or use computers with different resolutions the fixed div on the right gets pushed in and overlaps the center content.

So how can I have my side navigation fixed to not scroll with the page but not overlapping the content when zooming in or using other resolutions?

CSS for navigation div:

```
#navBox{
position: fixed;
padding: 6px;
border-radius: 8px; 
background: #DEDEDE;
right: 30px;
margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your content and navigation in another div and set the width of that to equal or greater than than nav-width + content-width. Or you can set this width on the body, but i would not recommend doing that.

Comment: it sounds a bit confused to me the way you say it. IMHO , it's the right way to do it. Set a fixed element all the way side to side of te screen  inside wich you style your nav as you would be in the flow (width, min-width, margin:auto, ..). So they always match overlapping. Confusing too ? :) some code should help

Comment: Im not sure I am following you guys. So for watson's suggestion I added   an outter div with a width greater:

Comment: I'm not sure I am following you guys. So for watson's suggestion I added an outer div around everything with a larger width and it didnt seem to do anything:
'<div class="allContent>
<div class="sideNav"> stuff </div>
<div class="mainContent"> more stuffffff </div>
</div>'
sideNav position is fixed and allContent's width is larger then both  the others. But when zooming in the side nav still pushes in horizontally over the mainContent. Is this what you meant for me to try? Thanks